# Apple TV no longer allows dictation into Search fields

Tags: appletv, siri, voice-dictation, siri-remote

On Apple TV, when searching for content in various apps, on the screen with an alphabet used to type into the Search form, we see a prompt inviting us to press the Siri button to dictate rather than type.

This feature used to work well, conveniently dictating rather than typing search terms into the current app.

Unfortunately, this no longer works. Despite the offer of the prompt to search within an app, holding down the Siri button to speak *always* has Siri do a search across all apps rather than within the current app.

How can I restore dictation within the current app’s Search form?